# Group by in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I have a query in SQL Server

```
SELECT
    k12_dms_contacts_master.prefix_id AS prefix,
    k12_dms_contacts_master.first_name,
    k12_dms_contacts_master.last_name,
    k12_dms_contacts_master.email,
    k12_dms_institution_master.inst_name,
    k12_dms_institution_master.address,
    k12_dms_cities.name AS city_name,
    k12_dms_zip_codes.zip_code,
    k12_dms_institution_master.type_id,
    k12_dms_contacts_institution_jobtitles.glevel_id,
    k12_dms_districts.name AS district_name,
    k12_dms_counties.name AS county_name,
    k12_dms_institution_master.state_id,
    k12_dms_institution_master.phone,
    k12_dms_contacts_institution_jobtitles.job_title_id
FROM
    k12_dms_institution_master
INNER JOIN k12_dms_contacts_institution_jobtitles ON k12_dms_contacts_institution_jobtitles.inst_id = k12_dms_institution_master.id
INNER JOIN k12_dms_contacts_master ON k12_dms_contacts_institution_jobtitles.contact_id = k12_dms_contacts_master.id
INNER JOIN k12_dms_cities ON k12_dms_cities.id = k12_dms_institution_master.city_id
INNER JOIN k12_dms_districts ON k12_dms_districts.id = k12_dms_institution_master.district_id
INNER JOIN k12_dms_counties ON k12_dms_counties.id = k12_dms_institution_master.county_id
INNER JOIN k12_dms_zip_codes ON k12_dms_zip_codes.id = k12_dms_institution_master.zip_code_id
WHERE
    k12_dms_zip_codes.zip_code IN ('92678', '92679', '92688', '92690', '92691', '92692', '92693', '92694', '92877',
                                   '92879', '92881', '92883')
ORDER BY
    k12_dms_institution_master.state_id,
    k12_dms_institution_master.inst_name ASC
```

Now I want to perform `GROUP BY` on Email address and Institution name but I am getting this error :

> Column 'k12_dms_contacts_master.prefix_id' is invalid in the select
>   list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or
>   the GROUP BY clause.

Any help would be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says it all.

You have created a group and since this column is not part of the "group by" nor an aggregation of all the groups column (like sum or count) you can't use it in the select clause.

Please note that the return of a group by is one row per group. Logically, that column would be different for any group member so it can not fit one line!

Comment: ^ What he said. Or, to be more consise: **each** field in the select statement **NOT** in used in an aggregate function **must** be in the group by clause. By my count, in the query in the question, the group by will have to contain 15 fields.

Comment: Yes but on grouping on all the fetched fields will give me error:The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.

Comment: Ok, so you have a text field? You cant use GROUP BY over text fields. try casting it to varchar (select and group by) and then using if you're sure if data falls within certain length